# Python throws error when deleting a directory that is open with windows explorer

Tags: python, windows-7, delete-file, shutil

I'm writing a code in Python, in which I check if a certain folder exists; if it does, I remove it and create a new one (with the same name). The code is as follows:

```
 if os.path.exists(output_folder):
     shutil.rmtree(output_folder)  
 os.makedirs(output_folder)
```

This code works fine, accept for when I have that specific `output_folder` open with the `windows explorer`. When it's open, I get the following error in my code:

```
WindowsError: [Error 5] Access is denied: [foldername]
```

Simultaneously, `windows explorer` switches itself to `foldername`'s parent directory, and throws an error.

Is there a way to make python ignore the error and continue running, or am I asking for something that is impossible due to the system?

I tried using `shutil.rmtree(output_folder, ignore_errors=True)` but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Python's exception handling to catch the error. You would also probably benefit from a short delay before creating the folder again to give Windows Explorer a chance to close:

```
import shutil
import time


try:    
    shutil.rmtree(output_folder)  
except WindowsError as e:
    print("Failed to delete")       # Or just pass

time.sleep(0.5)
os.makedirs(output_folder)
```

Comment: Thanks @MartinEvans; I think `sleep` is what did the job, because it doesn't throw the exception.

Comment: Adding the delay did it for me as I was having this Error 5 randomly.